# How to extract the title, authors, creation date of a PDF in Python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, pdfminer

I manage papers locally and rename each PDF file in the form of "creationdate_authors_title.pdf". Hence, extracting the title, authors, creation date of each paper from the PDF file automatically is required.

I have written a python script using the package pdfminer to extract info. However, for certain files, after parsing them, the file info stored in the dictionary doc.info[0] by using PDFDocument may not contain some keys such as "Author", or these keys' values are empty.

I'm wondering how can I locate the required info such as the paper's title directly from the PDF file using the function like "extract_pages". Or, more generally, how can I accurately and efficiently extract the info I required?

Any hint would be appreciated! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you have already done this correctly but some pdfs just don't have a "title" or "author".

Comment: That metadata is stored in the "\info" element in the "\trailer" object, and that element is completely optional.

Comment: Many thanks for all your comments. Seems like I can only rename some of the PDFs manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to extract all the metadata using the library PyPDF2

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
def get_info(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
        number_of_pages = pdf.getNumPages()
    
    print(info)
    author = info.author
    creator = info.creator
    producer = info.producer
    subject = info.subject
    title = info.title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'reportlab-sample.pdf'
    get_info(path)
```

As you see inside the `info` variable you have all you need. Check this [documentation](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/04/10/extracting-pdf-metadata-and-text-with-python/)